# Tuning ratio of Random Under Sampling with Grid Search in a unbalanced data set

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

As suggested on the title I would like to do a grid search on the ratio of my random under sampler. I would like to try the **ratios 10, 15 and 20 where ratio = 10 is number of resampled majority class / number of minority class.**

Example : if the minority class has 10 elements, the majority 1000, with a ratio of 5 I will have 10 minority and 50 majority. That's what suggests the documentation of Random Under Sampler.

https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html

```
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline as imbalanced_make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV 

pipe = imbalanced_make_pipeline(RandomUnderSampler(),
                            SMOTE(),
                            RandomForestClassifier())

gsc = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid= {'smote__ratio': [5, 10, 15],
                                            'randomforestclassifier__criterion': ["entropy"], 
                                            'randomforestclassifier__max_depth': np.arange(10,30,5), 
                                            'randomforestclassifier__min_samples_leaf': np.arange(5,15,3)},
               scoring='f1',cv=5, verbose=2)

grid_result = gsc.fit(X, y)
```

**I get this error :**

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Someone can help me please ? thanks.